# swiftで下のタブバーの画像を高画質にしたい

Tags: swift

StoryBoardだけで実現できますか？
現時点だと画質良い画像をセットするとそのままのサイズで表示されはみ出してしまいますので、24*24のサイズで開発しています

[image: ipad mini4でスクリーンショットを撮りました]

気にしなければいい話ですが、せっかくのRetinaディスプレイですので活用したいです
よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcodeの**Assets.xcassets**に登録することで、ドロー画像もアイコンにすることができるようになりました。TabBarItemのシステムアイコンも、間違いなくドローデータで作られています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

まず、Illustratorなどで、ドローデータを作成し、PDF書類を作ります。がんばって、Quartz2Dフレームワークを駆使して、Xcodeだけで、自作してもいいでしょう。タブバーアイコンなら、24×24ピクセルのサイズにします。
Assets.xcassets編集画面で、右クリックして、New Image Setを作成します。名称を適切なものに変えます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

新規セットの中で、右クリックして、Universalのセットを作ります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Attributes Inspectorを開いて、Scale FactorをSingle Vectorにします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Finderから、アイコンにしたいPDF書類を新規セットにドラッグします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

プログラム中で、拡張子なしで指定します。

Comment: 使えるのはPDFだけでしょうか？

Comment: @sugawara 「だけ」じゃもちろんありません。ビットマップ画像でも、Retina（x2）、iPhone6(s)Plus（x3）用を作成して、image setにドロップすれば、機種ごとに最適な解像度のアイコンを表示できます。

Comment: なるほど。実現できました。ありがとうございました

Comment: @sugawara 内容を修正・更新しました。画像の種類をVector（＝ドローデータ）と指定します。